# meaning: work out questions

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I saw the following example sentence in a dictionary, and am wondering whether "work out" means "**find the answers to**" or "**prepare**." And if it does not mean "find the answers to" here, could it have that meaning in some other context?

> I **work out my questions** in advance, just in case I get brain fade.

Comment: I think there is enough ambiguity here for it not to be *completely* clear if it's the understanding or phrasing of the questions that's being referred to or the answers themselves. Either interpretation seems reasonable to me, barring further context. However, I think it's *likely* that this is referring to the questions being answered.

Answer (score 1):

According to Macmillan Dictionary, [work out](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/work-out#work-out__1) means:

> "to solve a problem by doing a calculation"
>   **Example**:
>   I was born in 1947: you work
>   out my age.

So yes, the sentence means that the boy solves (finds the answers to) his questions earlier, in case he gets lazy in the future.

Comment: The dictionary is vague about the object of "work out": Is it "answers/solutions" or "the question" itself? Should I say "work out a solution/an answer" or "work out a question"?

Comment: @Apollyon when you workout a question, you are solving it. So you'd say "work out a question", NOT "work out a solution" (as that would literally mean solving a solution)

Comment: "work out a solution" is amply attested: https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=xyc4GzBrrvMC&pg=PA4&dq=%22work+out+a+solution%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOwPOxlKzjAhWwF6YKHd16D6MQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%22work%20out%20a%20solution%22&f=false

Comment: See also https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=I0FODwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1505&dq=%22work+out+a+solution%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOwPOxlKzjAhWwF6YKHd16D6MQ6AEITzAF#v=onepage&q=%22work%20out%20a%20solution%22&f=false